# api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, windows-10

It is not *-l1-2-0.dll nor *-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll but *-l1-2-1.dll that is missing.
I have a win8.1 Ent installing in Parallels Desktop on my MacBook Pro.
I'm trying to install a win10 on an external USB3.0 following [the tutorial](http://bleeptobleep.blogspot.fr/2013/02/mac-install-windows-7-or-8-on-external.html). 
On the last step in Step 3: Deploy the Windows installation image, I try to create the boot section using:

```
o:\windows\system32\bcdboot o:\windows /f ALL /s b:
```

but it pops up "The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." 
The windows installed in Parallels is 64bit, and the win10 I'm trying to install is also 64bit.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create a WindowsToGo drive.

[image]

Select the Windows 10 ISO and "Windows To Go" radio button.

[image]

It has a [fix for the issue](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/commit/d1eccbd10789b3e4650087f0d573f4dc4af6d8d3). It simply invokes the Windows 8.1 bcdboot.ee to avoid the error.